# libpng error invalid chunk type when loading png from memory

Tags: c++, buffer, libpng

I'm trying to load a PNG from a memory buffer so I can access the ImageData without having to save it as a file first.

The memory buffer contains a valid png-file, when using fwrite to save it as a file on disk I get the following image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13077624/test.png

This represents a depth Image received by a Kinect sensor, for those of you wondering.

This is the code that gives errors:

```
struct mem_encode
{
    char *buffer;
    png_uint_32 size;
    png_uint_32 current_pos;
};

void handle_data(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        cout<<"Saving as file: "<<determinePathExtension(PNGFrame,"png");
        FILE* fp=fopen("test.png","wb");
        fwrite(data_,bytes_transferred,1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
        //get PNG file info struct (memory is allocated by libpng)
        png_structp png_ptr = NULL;
        png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (!png_ptr) {

             std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't initialize png read struct" << std::endl;
             cin.get();
            return; //Do your own error recovery/handling here
        }
        // get PNG image data info struct (memory is allocated by libpng)
        png_infop info_ptr = NULL;
        info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
        if (!info_ptr) {
         std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't initialize png info struct" << std::endl;
         cin.get();
         png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, (png_infopp)0, (png_infopp)0);
         return; //Do your own error recovery/handling here
        }

        struct mem_encode pngdata;
        pngdata.buffer=data_;

        pngdata.size=(png_uint_32)bytes_transferred;
        pngdata.current_pos=0;
        png_set_read_fn(png_ptr,&pngdata, ReadData);
        //Start reading the png header
        png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);
        png_read_info(png_ptr,info_ptr);
        //... Program crashes here
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<error.message()<<" Bytes received: "<<bytes_transferred<<endl;
        delete this;
    }
}


static void ReadData(png_structp png_ptr, png_bytep outBytes,
    png_size_t byteCountToRead){
        struct mem_encode* p=(struct mem_encode*)png_get_io_ptr(png_ptr);
        size_t nsize=p->size + byteCountToRead;

        if(byteCountToRead>(p->size-p->current_pos)) png_error(png_ptr,"read error in read_data_memory (loadpng)");

        /* copy new bytes */
        memcpy(outBytes,p->buffer + p->size,byteCountToRead);
        p->current_pos+=byteCountToRead;
}
```

Calling the method results in the program crashing with the following error:

```
libpng error: [00][00][00][00]: invalid chunk type
```

data_ represents the the databuffer storing the PNG-image and is a char *.
Any help would be appreciated.

Sources I used:

- http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.0.3-manual.html
- http://blog.hammerian.net/2009/reading-png-images-from-memory/
- http://santosdev.blogspot.be/2012/08/loading-png-image-with-libpng-1512-or.html
- http://www.piko3d.net/tutorials/libpng-tutorial-loading-png-files-from-streams/

Could this be caused by network bytes being translated badly?

Comment: have you found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to read the PNG signature bytes.  Use

```
if (png_sig_cmp(data, 0, 8)
   png_error(png_ptr, "it's not a PNG file");
```

Then your

```
png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr,8);
```

lets libpng know you have already read the signature.

Or, you could use `png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 0);` and
let libpng do the checking for you.

Comment: I actually thought of that myself, but it didn't work. It did return 0 though, so the databuffer contained a valid PNG.

I've currently given up on the PNG decompression and returned to JPEG-decompression. It would be nice to fix this though, but it's not top priority anymore.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `ReadData` function is correct? Why do you start `memcpy` from the address `p->buffer + p->size` - isn't it the end of the buffer? And what does `nsize` do?